# Facebook app on fan page problems (error 404)

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I see this issue has appeared a few times but none of the solutions have worked for me.

Here is my app: https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=168373039912688

It's basically an image of a poster: http://www.clare-ents.com/test/facebook/index.html

I want this image to be the landing page of my fan page: http://www.facebook.com/ClareEnts

I've added this as the site URL on the developer page and added it to my fan page. When I click 'Go to application' on the Apps tab on my fan page I get an error 404. Where could I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The App is pointing to : http://www.clare-ents.com/help/facebook/index.html and that seems not to have anything.

But to make this app show a and image on the landing page you need to go to your app settings and change the Tab URL and point it to the image or HTML Poster you wish to display.

Then go to the app Page https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=168373039912688 and on the left menu click "Ad to My page", select the clareEnts page.

Last in your page settings select the default tab. This will be the tab where non-likers land. As an admin in wont work that way (you are always a fan is the behavior) so use another account for testing.